# Power Query M: Count in how many rows a certain substring occours

Tags: powerquery, m

I have this type of table in Power BI:

| id | isPromoter | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa-111-000 | false | sqe-432-w14/2aq-4ec-t66/aaa-111-000/ |
| sss-342-r34 | true | a3e-543-1sd/34d-245-svt/s3a-bnj-klo/**sss-342-r34**/ |
| hhy-e90-y7u | false | a3e-543-1sd/34d-245-svt/s3a-bnj-klo/**sss-342-r34**/hhy-e90-y7u/ |
| ... | ... | ... |

So, as you can see, the second id is contained in both in the second and in the third path; this only can happen if the user is a Promoter.

I would like another field which counts how many times each id is contained in all paths (beside itself); so it should be 0 if the user is not a promoter and >0 if it is.

| id | isPromoter | path | children |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa-111-000 | false | sqe-432-w14/2aq-4ec-t66/aaa-111-000/ | 0 |
| sss-342-r34 | true | a3e-543-1sd/34d-245-svt/s3a-bnj-klo/sss-342-r34/ | 3 |
| hhy-e90-y7u | false | a3e-543-1sd/34d-245-svt/s3a-bnj-klo/sss-342-r34/hhy-e90-y7u/ | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I know that there is the function Text.Contains([path],[id]) but it is only true for the current row. I don't know how to do the count for all rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column ... custom column ... name it children, use formula

```
= List.Count(List.FindText(#"PriorStepNameHere"[path],[id]))-1
```